# Is this limit right, or is there any way to deal with it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

calculate
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{nx^{1/2}}{1+n^2x}\sin^5{nx}dx$$
Because$$\left|\dfrac{nx^{1/2}}{1+n^2x}\right|\leqslant\frac{1}{2}.$$
So$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{nx^{1/2}}{1+n^2x}\sin^5{nx}dx=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{nx^{1/2}}{1+n^2x}\sin^5{nx}dx=0$$

Comment: Good start with Dominated Convergence.

Comment: @Sean Roberson So my answer is not wrong？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is totally right but you can also just squeeze it:

\begin{eqnarray*}0
& \leq & \int_{0}^{1}\left|\dfrac{nx^{1/2}}{1+n^2x}\sin^5{nx}\right|dx \\
& \leq & \frac 1n \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^{1/2}}{\frac1{n^2}+x}dx \\
& \leq & \frac 1n \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}dx \\
& = & \frac 2n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask if this function is Riemannian integrable?Will it affect squeeze？

Comment: @夜愿1998 I am not quite sure what exactly you are asking about.

Comment: Sorry, my English is poor.I mean, does integrability affect scaling?

Comment: @夜愿1998 : You can squeeze as I did as long as the bounding functions are still properly or improperly Riemann or even Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: If you have an (in whatever sense) integrable function $f(x)$, then for any scalar $t$ the scaled function $t\cdot f(x)$ remains integrable and you have $\int_a^b t\cdot f(x)\, dx = t\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I think too much

Comment: You are welcome. And it is good to think things through once in a while :-)

Comment: Can you look at this problem for me, thank you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984521/if-f0-f-prime0-0-and-fx-leqslant-fxfx-then-fx-equ/3984595#3984595

Comment: @夜愿1998 At the moment I am a bit busy. But maybe later.